# Kendo Grid Pass Form Data as Parameter Angular to MVC

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am switching from the Angular UI-Grid to the Kendo UI-Grid in my application.  Currently, search criteria is collected via a search form then sent to my MVC Controller method via a Service (like below):

```
generalsearchService.submitSearch($scope.form)
  .success(function (data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = (data);
  });
```

However, I cannot figure out how to pass the form data to the method using the Kendo grid.  I have tried the following:

```
var form = $scope.form;
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
        transport: {
            read: "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Search/SubmitCriteria",
            type: "POST",
            data:{form: form}

        },
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total"
        },
        pageSize: 25,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true

    }),
```

My MVC Controller method (first line):

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitCriteria(ContractorSearchViewModel form)
```

> Update:  I was able to pass the parameter to the controller by changing the read url to a function like below:

```
read: function() {
                generalsearchService.submitSearch(form)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        return data;
                    });
            }
```

However, even though the method executes correctly, the grid does not update with the new data.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the service call above was hitting the MVC controller, the data was not populating the grid.  The service call needed to be tweaked a little.  Here is what finally worked:

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    generalsearchService.submitSearch(e.data, form)
                        .then(function success(response) {
                            e.success(response.data);
                        });
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total"
            },
            pageSize: 25,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true

        }),
```

"e.data" actually sends the Page, PageSize, Filters and Sort information while "form" is the collected form data which serves as parameters for the stored procedure. I also had to remove "[DataSourceRequest]" for the DataSourceRequest to actually send all information using my service.  The http call in the service looks like this:

```
  this.submitSearch = function (command, form) {
return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Search/SubmitCriteria', {'command': command, 'form': form});
```

};

and the MVC controller method looks like this:

```
      public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitCriteria(DataSourceRequest command, ContractorSearchViewModel form)
```

I hope this helps someone else.  Happy coding!